# Late 70's or early 80's apocalyptic sci-fi show about a boy in a deserted England. Similar to John Christopher's "Empty World"

Tags: story-identification, tv, post-apocalyptic

TV movie / series, possibly BBC, seemed to be filmed in England (from memory). I saw it in Australia when I was a child in late 70' early 80's.

It could be movie or series. It was a last person on Earth, "cosy catastrophe", apocalyptic situation where a boy awakens to a deserted England(?). There is a scene where he finds a Jaguar car (possibly red) and goes about trying to solve the mystery and find others etc. That is really all I remember.

Having done some research, my memory of the program is reminiscent of a novel called *Empty World* by John Christopher. This is an apocalyptic fiction novel aimed at an adolescent audience. Set in 1977 and centered around Neil Miller and his struggle to come to terms with the loss of his parents in a car crash and the subsequent 'Calcutta Plague' that decimates the adult population. The novel is set in England in the late 1970s.

That sounds a lot like my memory. Part of the description for the novel *Empty World* even mentions this scene:

> Neil leaves for London, taking first a manual Mini which he has difficulty driving, followed by an automatic Jaguar.

This is similar to the scene I remember.

I can't find any reference to this becoming a film in England. There is a reference to a German TV adaptation of Empty world, but cannot find any more info about that. Maybe another program 'borrowed' aspects of *Empty World*.

Comment: It really does sound like Empty World. Here's the German film on Youtube. Does it look at all familiar?  Maybe you saw a dubbed version.   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_C0P6M0kFgE

Comment: Do you remember if the population disappeared literally overnight? In Empty World, people were dying from disease over the course a few weeks (maybe even months)

Comment: Thank you for the replies, and apologies for my very delayed reply (sick parents, new laptop etc. Lost the link and then totally forgot about this question until now). Unfortunately, it was NOT that German version of "Empty World" in the Youtube link...

No I do not remember if  the people took a while to die or not, but if asked to guess I would tend toward an overnight disappearance. Now I am back to thinking it was indeed a British programme that perhaps borrowed a few ideas from that book.

Thank you again for the replies. Much appreciated.